# How to add action before "gf"?

Tags: neovim, command-line

I'm using NVIM 0.8.2

I'd like to replace the default `gf` command (goto file under the cursor) to do something before and after the action.

For example:

```
echo "do something before"
goto file/dir under cursor
echo "do something after"
```

I can't find what command `gf` is calling, how can I do this?

Comment: `gf` doesn't "call" any "command", that's not how it works. `gf` *is* the "command". f you want to override `gf`, make a custom mapping that does what you want. A one line if that's enough or one that calls a custom function if not.

Comment: I made a few more dig with the problem what I'm trying to solve, I think the issue is not on `gf`, but my `pwd` changes when I `gf` or `:e` to a folder, like `:e ./src`, so my `pwd` become `<projectPath>/src` instead of `<projectPath>`. (I have `autochdir` off)

Comment: I have seen quite a few Neovim users complain about arbitrarily changed working directory recently. I don't use that thing, though, so I will stop here but others might be interested to know what file manager you are using.

Comment: At any rate, to run the `gf` command, you can use `:normal! gf`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
function Beforegf()
    "do something here
endfunction
function Aftergf()
    "do something here
endfunction
nnoremap gf :<c-u>call Beforegf()<cr>gf:<c-u>call Aftergf()<cr>
```

if `Beforegf()` is something that will move your cursor, you'll need to adjust accordingly. Example:

```
function Beforegf()
    " yank the WORD under the cursor into the f register
    norm! "fyiW
    pu='This is the line after the filename'
endfunction
function Aftergf()
    "do something here
endfunction
" Use the :e command with the contents of the f register to get the filename we yanked
nnoremap gf :<c-u>call Beforegf()<cr>:<c-u>exe 'e '.@f<cr>:<c-u>call Aftergf()<cr>
```

At any rate, you can use the normal command `yiW` followed by the Ex command `execute 'edit '.@"` as a *rough* equivalent of `gf`. I would warn, however, that a WORD is not the exact same thing as a filepath. If you want a really robust solution, take another look at `:help gf` and possibly incorporate the contents of the `isfname` option into your method of determining what to yank.

Comment: `nnoremap gf :<c-u>call Beforegf()<cr>gf:<c-u>call Aftergf()<cr>` since `nnoremap` helps prevent the inner `gf` from recurring into the mapping, and after `:…<CR>` we're in normal mode…

Comment: Wow! I think both way works for me? And I learned new thing here (`norm! gf`)

Comment: @ Lai, glad to help. @D.BenKnoble, hah, thanks...that was really silly on my part. Will edit my answer.